# Determine if the vectors form a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an exercise about determining if the vectors form a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{4}.$ I do not understand much about this. Could you please guide me on how to do it? Thank you so much, [here is the exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7k6j.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $W\subset V$, and $V$ is a vector space, it is enough to check:

1. For every $w_1,w_2 \in W$, $w_1+w_2 \in W$
2. For every $w\in W$ and scalar $\alpha\in \Bbb F$, $\alpha w\in W$

for $W$ to be a subspace of $V$. Goes without saying, every subspace must contain $0\in V$. Can you take it from here?

---

To answer your particular question:

(a) Yes, this is a subspace. In fact, any equation of the form $ax_1 + bx_2 + cx_3 + dx_4 = 0$ defines a subspace of $V$, where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb F$.
(b) Not a subspace! $x_1x_3 = x_2x_4$ is anyway a *non-linear* relation between the coordinates of $x$, so I wouldn't expect it to define a subspace. It suffices to find a counterexample, as done by @X.Li in the comments.
(c) Not a subspace! $x_3 \ge x_4 \implies -x_3 \le -x_4$, so if $z\in \{x\in\mathbb R^4: x_3\ge x_4\}$, then $-z\notin \{x\in\mathbb R^4: x_3\ge x_4\}$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am done with the a/ part.
For the b/ part, when I check if w1+ w2∈W or not.Let w1 = [a1 a2 a3 a4], w2 = [b1 b2 b3 b4]. Then x1*x3 - x2 * x4 = 0( from the given condition), then (a1+b1)(a3 + b3) - (a2 + b2)(a4 + b4) = 0 => (a1a3 - a2a4) + ( b1b3 - b2b4) + a1b3 - a2b4 + b1a3 - b2a4 = 0. From here I do not know how to handle (a1b3 - a2b4 + b1a3 - b2a4)? because (a1a3 - a2a4) + ( b1b3 - b2b4) = 0

Comment: @HaiLuu For the b/ part, note that if $w_1, w_2 \in W$ but $w_1 + w_2 \in W$ does not always hold, giving one counterexample will suffice. Here if we let $w_1 = [2,1,2,4]$ and $w_2 = [2,4,2,1]$. Then both $w_1, w_2 \in W$ and $w_1 + w_2 = [2,1,2,4] + [2,4,2,1] = [4,5,4,5]$. However, since $4 \times 4 = 16 \neq 25 = 5 \times 5$, we know that $w_1 + w_2 = [4,5,4,5] \notin W$, which indicates that $W$ in b/ part is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ (not closed under addition). Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that's right! Similarly for $(c)$, suppose $x  = (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ is such that $x_3 \ge x_4$. $-1\cdot x = -x$ doesn't satisfy the same property, since $-x_3 \le -x_4$. This shows that $(c)$ doesn't form a subspace either.